# Query error in MS ACCESS 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

please help me this query which throws an error throws an error:Missing semicolon(;) at the end of statement

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO rsANALYSIS values ( " & _
  "Chemname, Startvalue, StopValue, Received, [Usage], Quotum ) " & _
  "SELECT '" & rsMainList("handelsnaam") & "', " & StartStock & _
  ", " & StopStock & ", " & Stockreceived & ", " & Stockusage & _
  ", " & rsMainList("quotumlt") & ";"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure all your variables contain values? If not, you will get the above error.

For the most part, you are better off with parameters:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb

sSQL = "INSERT INTO rsANALYSIS values ( " & _
  "Chemname, Startvalue, StopValue, Received, [Usage], Quotum ) " & _
  "Values ([p1],[p2],[p3],[p4,[p5],[p6])"


''Temporary query
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", sSQL)
''No need to worry about quotes etc
qdf.Parameters("p1") = rsMainList("handelsnaam")
qdf.Parameters("p2") = StartStock
qdf.Parameters("p3") = StopStock 
qdf.Parameters("p4") = Stockreceived 
qdf.Parameters("p5") = Stockusage 
qdf.Parameters("p6") = rsMainList("quotumlt")  

qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of this, probably at the end of the INSERT query

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO rsANALYSIS values ( Chemname, Startvalue, 
StopValue, Received, [Usage], Quotum ); 

SELECT '" & rsMainList("handelsnaam") & "', " & StartStock & ", " & StopStock & ", " & Stockreceived & ", " & Stockusage & ", " & rsMainList("quotumlt") & ";"
```

Also make sure the unquoted variables are not empty

Comment: @Romeu Alright. The query seems OK unless those concatenated variables are empty

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 syntax styles for an Access INSERT statement:

1. `INSERT INTO TableName (field list) VALUES (value list)`
2. `INSERT INTO TableName (field list) SELECT statement`

It appears your `INSERT` statement is using a mix of both styles.  Try it this way (without the `VALUES` key word):

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO rsANALYSIS ( " & _
  "Chemname, Startvalue, StopValue, Received, [Usage], Quotum ) " & _
  "SELECT '" & rsMainList("handelsnaam") & "', " & StartStock & _
  ", " & StopStock & ", " & Stockreceived & ", " & Stockusage & _
  ", " & rsMainList("quotumlt") & ";"
```

Comment: that's true..the last variable was empty for one row which resulted in error